# Compare values in array and remove bigger one

Tags: c++

So basically I need to compare first array value with next array value, if the first array value is bigger then remove it from the list.

For example:

```
User enters: 1 2 4 3 5 6 4
Output shpuld be : 1 2 3 5 4
```

Atm I have no idea how to fix this, also when I'm trying to compare last entered number it just compares to 0.

```
void find_and_delete(int *vals, int len){
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){

    if (vals[i] > vals[i+1]){
        vals[i] = ' ';
    }




oid printt(int *vals, int len){
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){

        if (vals[i] != ' '){
            cout << vals[i] << endl;
```

Comment: You output shows 5 before 4? Shouldn't this be removed too?

Comment: Your code snippet is extremely incomplete. Present your [MCVE].

Comment: dave - No, it should check from array.
For example:  3 5 2 3 4 5. It should check if 3 is bigger than 5 if not, then print it out, if 5 is bigger than 2(remove it)..
Out put should be: 32345

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
void find_and_delete(int *vals,int len)
{
   if(len>0)
   {
   for (int i = 0; i < len-1; i++)
   {

         if (vals[i] > vals[i+1]){
            vals[i] = ' ';
         }

   }
   }

}


void printt(int *vals, int len){
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){

        if (vals[i] != ' '){
           cout << vals[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

It won't consider last element.

Comment: Why do you assume 32 is not a valid number in the input array?

Comment: It's probably worth pointing out why you have written the loop as you have, rather than just write `for (int i=0; i<len-1; i++)`  (your way handles empty lists - an alternative would be:  `if (len > 0) { for (int i=0; i<len-1; ...`

Comment: You are right @MartinBonner. I didn't notice that before. Edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

For resizable array, you can use **std::vector** with `#include <vector>`

**for loop upper bound is `len - 1` not len**

```
std::vector<int> results;

for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++){

    if (vals[i] > vals[i+1]){
    }
    else{
        results.push_back(vals[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try like as below,

```
int[] t = {1,2,4,3,5,6,4}; // create an array of integers
    for (int i=0; i<t.length-1; i++) {
        for(int j = i+1; j<t.length; j++){
            if (t[i]<t[j]){                  // if j is bigger than i
                cout << t[i];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is not C++: `int[] t` is not the way to declare arrays in C++, and there is no `length` attribute.

Comment: just for the record `int t[] {1,2,4,3,5,6,4};` would be fine though. The algorithm here isn't particularly good either though.

Comment: @jhbh true, but he's also using `t.length`, so it doesn't look like a simple typo.

Comment: @Ionut I completely agree. I was just showing a C++ way to do it, in case anyone didn't see why it was wrong.